# Use classic GUI and not Unity

Tags: unity, system-installation, gui

While installing Ubuntu, is it possible for the user to choose between Unity or the classic interface?  I am not a big fan of the Unity interface.  To me it is not very user friendly.  I prefer the classic GUI and I spend an hour or more jumping through hoops to be able to get the classic look.

Comment: You are looking for Ubuntu GNOME, which is a "flavor" of Ubuntu: https://ubuntugnome.org/

Comment: What is "classic GUI"?

Comment: If you liked "old-school" Ubuntu, I think you would like **Ubuntu MATE**. https://ubuntu-mate.org/ (It's my favorite ubuntu flavor.) It uses the old GNOME2-style desktop, but with lots of modern updates and improvements.

Comment: GNOME is what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to install Ubuntu with another desktop environment your choice is from downloading the [appropriate flavour](https://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours):

> - [Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/) — Ubuntu for education
> - [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/) — Ubuntu with the **GNOME desktop** environment
> - [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) — Ubuntu with the **K Desktop** environment
> - [Ubuntu Kylin](http://www.ubuntukylin.com/) — Ubuntu localised for China
> - [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.me/) — Ubuntu that uses **LXDE**
> - [Mythbuntu](http://www.mythbuntu.org/) — Designed for creating a home theatre PC with **MythTV**
> - [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/) — Designed for multimedia editing and creation
> - [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) — Ubuntu with the **XFCE desktop** environment
> - [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) — Ubuntu with the **MATE desktop** environment
> - [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/) — Simplicity & Elegance – **Budgie desktop** powered by Ubuntu

By installing default [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/) we will install the Unity desktop.

Still, it is possible to also use the classical GNOME desktop of earlier version by adding the [GNOME-session flashback package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-session-flashback) later. It will then be given as an option on then next login.

```
sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try other desktop environments.  Ubuntu Gnome has a "Gnome Classic" login setting which gives you a menu.  KDE (Kubuntu) also comes with a menu.  For beginners my opinion is that Gnome is easier to deal with, but if you want good video editing or other KDE programs then it might be better to go with KDE.

You can download Ubuntu with the different desktop environments already set up (which is less likely to be buggy), or if Unity is already installed then you can open a terminal and type 
        sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
or 
        sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Other options are to try a live disk of the different environments to see which you prefer, or to install a virtual machine like VirtualBox and install the different environments in that so you don't mess up your current installation.